# Xcode and Interface Builder randomly stopped talking

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So I was working on an XCode project and IBOutlets and IBActions were all working fine throughout the entire project, then randomly I tried to add a IBOutlet and I went to Interface Builder and the outlet would not show up when I clicked on the File's Owner icon. So I tried deleting the UIViewController and the UIView and made another, and then I couldn't connect the File's Owner to the XCode class. It wasn't even showing up in the list of Classes. So basically XCode and Interface Builder have completely stopped talking to each other and I have no idea why.

Comment: Try this: Clean the product, restart XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building the project right after you added the IBOutlet, then go to IB. Also, which Xcode version is this?